# Rollback of method with empty 'rollbackFor' property

Tags: java, spring, transactions, rollback, transactional

When a with [`@Transactional`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) annotated method throws an Exception, but no classes are declared in [`rollbackFor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#rollbackFor%28%29), will the transaction be rolled back or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default transaction is rolled back for unchecked exceptions (subclasses of `RuntimeException` and `Error`), and not rolled back for checked exceptions.

This behaviour can be customized by `rollbackFor` and `noRollbackFor` attributes.

**See also:**

- [10.5.3 Rolling back a declarative transaction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back)